# Toilet smells like sewer gas, but only in the winter

Tags: toilet

I've changed the wax ring twice. Every year without fail as soon as the temps dip in the 50s, especially if it's a windy day, the toilet starts stinking. For the life of me I can't figure it out.

As soon as spring comes, the smell goes away.

Comment: You sure its from the toilet?  Any chance it's from a nearby sink instead?  Does the toilet rock at all or is it solid?  When you replaced the wax ring, did it appear to have any gaps or leak spots?

Comment: In that bathroom there are two sinks, a shower, a tub, then a toilet and bidet in a smaller enclosed area. The smell certainly seems to be coming from the toilet. Every morning I run all of them. No rocking. Wax rings I removed looked perfect.

Answer (score 2):

[image]Two years later after having a couple of plumbers out and everyone scratching their heads. One of them told me the only thing he's ever heard like that was from another plumber who told him to caulk around the base of the toilet.

I gave it a try. Substantial improvement but still a small amount of smell. After a couple of days I put my nose down by it and I couldn't smell anything. Then I pulled the plastic cover off the bolt and I could smell it as clear as day.

In addition the bolt had some rot. Although there was never any sign of leakage, it seems there's at least enough moisture to cause problems. I'm going to tear into it Saturday and inspect and replace the wax ring once again.

I just wanted to post this in case anyone else ran into a similar problem and finds it in search results.

Comment: Do you have any theory on the seasonality? Ventilation with exterior air shut down during winter months?

Comment: The only thing I can come up with is that the drop in temperature causes everything to contract and there's some micro gap that allows gas out but not water. Seems like a stretch though. I'll post an update after I remove tomorrow.

Comment: Is the flange too low or is it loose or is there a crack in the pipe past the flange or in the throat of the toilet before the flange?

Comment: I pulled it apart today and it was clear that I had a bad wax ring. One side was more compressed than the other so I likely did it during the install. The surrounding area was just barely wet. I cleaned it all up and ran a powerful fan on it and ended up going with a rubber seal this time. So far so good.